# How to validate array of objects in an async function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, express, object

I am sending array of objects to server and trying to validate it, but I fail it will not do anything, if array is empty or neither it is valid, it just does not work, and I want to know why?

Here is code I use:

```
 const ingredientValidator = ingredients.some(({ingredient, quantity})=>{
        ingredient.trim().length == 0 || quantity.trim().length == 0
      }) 

  if(ingredientValidator){
     return res.status(409).send({
       message: 'fully point ingredients'
     })  
  }
```

what is problem with this?

P.S example of array of objects:

```
[  
   {  
      ingredient:'foo',
      quantity:'bar'
   },
   {  
      ingredient:'foo',
      quantity:'bar'
   },
   {  
      ingredient:'foo',
      quantity:'bar'
   }
]
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Please read section on [mcve]. Also, *"it just does not work"* is not specific enough to be helpful. 1. What do you expect it to do and/or what is the expected result? 2. What are the actual results and/or behavior? 3. Provide an example of the input. 4. Provide an example of desired results from said input. 5. Provide *actual* results of said input. BTW did not downvote...yet.

Comment: @zer00ne Thanks for point. I think i admitted that i wanted it to validate array if it is empty or not. 2. I also admitted that it does not do anything. 3. I provided example of input in "P.S" 4. As I said i wanted to validate array. 5. TBH I do not get what you mean.  Thanks for not downvoting LOL

Comment: *"If array is empty or neither it is valid"* An empty array is `[]`. It looks as if you are looking if a key or value of an object exists, and this object is within an array that is not empty `[{...},{...}]`. Also the title claims that you are using an `async function` but there aren't any. If you read on what a [mcve] is, you might learn why certain code is asked for (not every question warrants further explanation but  poorly written questions almost always do).

Comment: In first term I might chose words wrongly and I expect that stackoverflow's community will be able to get what I mean and i think you do too. but I can not agree you with second term. Why I must write down what function is it. I admitted that  `ingredientValidator` function is inside async function. for example it is `router.post('/route', async (req,res)=>{})` does it change anything? I do not think so. The main thing that i should said about outer scope I have already said. (it is async function)

Comment: Why even mention `async function` at all if it isn't relevant? Regardless, I don't see why would carry on with this useless thread of comments when you already have the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57234316/2813224). That's why you posted (poorly) a question in the first place, correct?

Comment: To prevent using synchronous methods in answers like `map` and please be more regardful and yes I agree with you that we should not carry on comments about this but it would not be correct from me to not reply on your problem about how should i provide minimal reproduciple example when I already did so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to alter the return of `ingredientValidator`:

```js
const ingredientValidator = ingredients.some(({ingredient, quantity})=>{
  return ingredient.trim().length == 0 || quantity.trim().length == 0
});

// or

const ingredientValidator = ingredients.some(({ingredient, quantity})=>
  ingredient.trim().length == 0 || quantity.trim().length == 0
);
```

When you have curly brackets after the arrow, it's essentially a normal function block that needs a `return` in order to pass anything out. You can also just remove the curly blocks and it should act as expected to get the implicit return.